# use js more than once in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

what I'm doing is very simple, I do change the image source when the mouse pass over it then put the old one back when its out..

```
<img id="Image1" src="../../Images/M2.jpg" onmouseover="roll_over('../../Images/M3.jpg','Image1')" onmouseout="roll_over('../../Images/M2.jpg','Image1')"/>
```

using this javascript:

```
function roll_over(img_src,id) {
document.getElementById(id).src = img_src;
}
```

I found that JavaScript doesn't update the image as it moves to another image, it only change the first image that the mouse pass over it, and I need it to change every image it passes over.

wt can I do to solve this situation?

Comment: Are you using unique IDs for each element on the page?

Comment: Try using `this` instead of the element id (Image1) that you are passing. This will save you all the `id`s.

Comment: Gabe yes, but now I'm using 'this', much better, thnx ssapkota!

Comment: @Evanescence - Yes I know, you selected my answer.

Comment: hehe I thought u're another person :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting it like this:

```
function roll_over(ctrl, img_src) {
   ctrl.src = img_src;
}

<img id="Image1" src="../../Images/M2.jpg" onmouseover="roll_over(this, '../../Images/M3.jpg')" onmouseout="roll_over(this, '../../Images/M2.jpg')"/>
```